# Python generic function with list of generic types

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, python-3.10

I'm trying to create a generic function in Python which will return a list of class instances and I'm having trouble making it work.

Let's take it a step back with a simpler example - a generic function which will return the provided class instance:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type


class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a: str):
        self.a = a

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__} a={self.a}"


class Foo2(Foo):
    pass


TFoo = TypeVar("TFoo", bound=Foo)


def init(t: Type[TFoo], a: str) -> TFoo:
    return t(a)


o1: Foo = init(Foo, "A")
print(o1)  # "Foo a=A"
o2: Foo2 = init(Foo2, "B")
print(o2)  # "Foo2 a=B"
```

So far so good. But now I want to create a function which works with a list of Foos. Here we go:

```
TFoo_co = TypeVar("TFoo_co", bound=list[Foo], covariant=True)


def init2(t: Type[TFoo_co], a: list[str]) -> TFoo_co:
    return t(a)  # This doesn't work


o3: list[Foo] = init2(list[Foo], ["A"])
print(o3)
o4: list[Foo2] = init2(list[Foo2], ["B"])
print(o4)
```

This doesn't work. And I haven't really found a way to do it. In init2 the t Type is a list, but I haven't found a way to access the "internal" class' constructor. Any tips? Or is this simply not possible? Python 3.10 btw.

Comment: `typing.get_origin(t)(map(typing.get_args(t)[0], a))`?

Comment: @MechanicPig Ooh, this looks promising! I'll give it a try when I'm next to my computer again. Thanks!